# SQL return database name in a query comparing one table across three databases

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a query that compares one table across three databases.

My query code is:

```
SELECT item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type
FROM
(
    SELECT item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type
        FROM [Arborg_Test_App].[dbo].item
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type 
        FROM [Teulon_Test_App].[dbo].item
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type
        FROM [PA_Test_App].[dbo].item
) data

GROUP BY item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

And it works great, it compares the table *item* across the three databases and only returns rows where the data in the selected columns doesn't match between the three databases.

My issue is, in the results that return I can't tell which row is from what database. My query results:
[image]

What I need is an additional column in my query results that shows the database name for each row.

Comment: Not related to your question, but instead of group by and having clauses, could you not simply change your union all's to simple unions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are looking for singletons, you can just add the db name to each subquery and then use `max()` in the outer query:

```
SELECT item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type,
       max(db) as thedb
FROM
(
    SELECT item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type, 'arbord' as db
        FROM [Arborg_Test_App].[dbo].item
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type, 'teulon'
        FROM [Teulon_Test_App].[dbo].item
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type, 'pa'
        FROM [PA_Test_App].[dbo].item
) data
GROUP BY item, description, stocked, product_code, cost_method, cost_type
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```